# Getting "Quota 'CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 in region asia-south1" error while add an instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota

as titile, I checked the project quota, it display the limitation of CPU quota is '0' in the region of asia-south1, please guide me how to do the next, thanks.

Comment: Please add more information. Like which cloud provider you are using.

Comment: Sorry, it's GCP. I've follow all instructions to finish the setup of an instance in the region of asia-south1, but got the error message while I built the instance in final step. Furthermore, no problem when I did the same steps in other region.

Answer (score 5):

I am getting the exact same error. The usual step is to request for a quota raise in the specific region (asia-south1).

1. You may go to [console.cloud.google.com/admin/quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/admin/quotas) page (for your specific project), which lists a table of all the quotas for the selected project.
2. Select the [limit-name "CPUs"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCKSU.png) from the table there. Click on All quotas to modify current CPU limit for your desired region.
3. For instance, asia-south1 [shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDRVl.png) its limited to 0. You can edit it and send your request.

Usually, this takes care of your request immediately (modulo 15 minutes wait time)
However, doing so, did not help me in this region (asia-south1). This seems to be a recent issue. I am able to create instances in other regions but not here!

----EDIT 4th Jan 21---

Just received an update from Google cloud support team:
"After careful evaluation, we have determined that we are unable to provide the requested quota increase for your project  at this time as we are temporarily restricting access to this region (asia-south1)."
So, that is the reason why any request to increase the quota will not work in this region. Will update this post if the support team provides any further update for lifting this restriction.

---- Edit 17 Sep 2021
I am able to increase quota for the region now. Not facing this issue anymore as Google has started granting request for new quotas here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend deploying and balancing your workload across multiple zones and regions to reduce the likelihood of an outage and have access to multiple resource pools when you need to expand quickly. Please review this documentation [1] which outlines how to build resilient and scalable architectures on Google Cloud Platform.

To prevent this outage in the future there is also the option of using  reservations that guarantees Google Cloud capacity, see the documentation[2] for details on how to use this feature.

Have a nice day!

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a restriction on the zone, I faced the same issue its caused by the quota

*compute.googleapis.com/cpus*

on viewing details of the error region *asia-south1*

[Refer screenshot of the quota for the region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKDEi.png)

So if you see the last column it says limit 0 and that's the reason the error pops up